# Mix custom memory management and Thrust in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, memory-management, thrust

In my project, I have implemented a custom memory allocator to avoid unneccessary calls to `cudaMalloc` once the application has "warmed up". Moreover, I use custom kernels for basic array filling, arithmetic operations between arrays, etc. and would like to simplify my code by using `Thrust` and getting rid of these kernels. Every array on the device is created and accessed through raw pointers (for now) and I'd like to use  `device_vector` and `Thrust`s methods on these objects, but I find myself converting between raw pointers and `device_ptr<>` all the time, somewhat cluttering up my code.

My rather vague question: How would/do you organize the usage of custom memory management, `Thrust`s array methods and calls to custom kernels in the most readable way?

Comment: You can create a custom allocator to use with ```device_vector```.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I was searching the documentation and all over the place to no avail, could you provide a pointer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like all standard c++ containers, you can customize how `thrust::device_vector` allocates storage by providing it with your own ["allocator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_%28C++%29). By default, `thrust::device_vector`'s allocator is `thrust::device_malloc_allocator`, which allocates (deallocates) storage with `cudaMalloc` (`cudaFree`) when Thrust's backend system is CUDA.

Occasionally, it is desirable to customize the way `device_vector` allocates memory, such as in the OP's case, who would like to sub-allocate storage within a single large allocation performed at program initialization. This can avoid overhead which may be incurred by many individual calls to the underlying allocation scheme, in this case, `cudaMalloc`.

A simple way to provide `device_vector` a custom allocator is to inherit from `device_malloc_allocator`. One could in principle author an entire allocator from scratch, but with an inheritance approach, only the `allocate` and `deallocate` member functions need to be provided. Once the custom allocator is defined, it can be provided to `device_vector` as its second template parameter.

This example code demonstrates how to provide a custom allocator which prints a message upon allocation and deallocation:

```
#include <thrust/device_malloc_allocator.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
  struct my_allocator : thrust::device_malloc_allocator<T>
{
  // shorthand for the name of the base class
  typedef thrust::device_malloc_allocator<T> super_t;

  // get access to some of the base class's typedefs

  // note that because we inherited from device_malloc_allocator,
  // pointer is actually thrust::device_ptr<T>
  typedef typename super_t::pointer   pointer;

  typedef typename super_t::size_type size_type;

  // customize allocate
  pointer allocate(size_type n)
  {
    std::cout << "my_allocator::allocate(): Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    // defer to the base class to allocate storage for n elements of type T
    // in practice, you'd do something more interesting here
    return super_t::allocate(n);
  }

  // customize deallocate
  void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
  {
    std::cout << "my_allocator::deallocate(): Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    // defer to the base class to deallocate n elements of type T at address p
    // in practice, you'd do something more interesting here
    super_t::deallocate(p,n);
  }
};

int main()
{
  // create a device_vector which uses my_allocator
  thrust::device_vector<int, my_allocator<int> > vec;

  // create 10 ints
  vec.resize(10, 13);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ nvcc my_allocator_test.cu -arch=sm_20 -run
my_allocator::allocate(): Hello, world!
my_allocator::deallocate(): Hello, world!
```

In this example, note that we hear from `my_allocator::allocate()` once upon `vec.resize(10,13)`. `my_allocator::deallocate()` is invoked once when `vec` goes out of scope as it destroys its elements.

Comment: Thank you for your incredibly helpful answer!